# Lua String Pattern Checking if a Character is Not in a Word

Tags: regex, lua

So what I am trying to achieve in Lua is a string pattern that checks to see if a certain character, given its position in the string, is part of a word or not. As an example, say I have the string:

```lua
str = "exp(x)"
```

What I want to achieve is to find a string pattern that when I run the following code:

```lua
do
    local newStr = str:gsub(STRING-PATTERN, 10)
    print(newStr)
end
```

It correctly prints out:

```lua
"exp(10)"
```

Instead of:

```lua
"e10p(10)"
```

So far I have tried a few, but none really work. Here are a few examples of the ones I have tried:

STRING-PATTERN = "[%A[x]%A]?"

```lua
"exp(-10"
```

STRING-PATTERN = "[%A[x]%A*]?"

```lua
"e10p1010"
```

I'm not exactly sure why these won't work, and I'm almost positive there is a regular expression for this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might have to write a parser to do what you want here.

Comment: Please include a list of strings and desired results. Also include examples where you don't want to find anything.

Answer (score 1):

## You don't need a substiturion

`string.gsub` is a function to substitute something in a string. That is why the `10` occurs in your results. 
*By the way, you replace what you found by a litteral, but you can also includ what you found in the replacement.*

```
print(str:gsub("[%a[x]%a*]?", '<%0>')) --> <exp>(<x>)    2
```

*The `2` indicates it found two results.*

If you are unfamiliar with functions returning multiple results, [read this](https://www.lua.org/pil/5.1.html)

You need `string.find` to find something. This function returns the begin and end position of what it found, but you can also make it return a third value: the text it found, by enclosing your pattern in brackets.

```
print(str:find("[%a[x]%a*]?")) --> 1  2  exp
```

## Your patterns are wrong.

To be honest, I don't understand how your pattern works, but there is generally no need for square brackets in a search string.

Assuming you are looking for strings that from `Try exp(x) out`, you only need `exp(x)`, you are looking for any x, includng all non-white space characters in front od it or behind it. Non white space characters are coded as `%S`, and you need 0 or more of them at both sides, so

```
str = "exp(x)"
print(str:find("(%S*x%S*)")) -->  1    6    exp(x)

str = "Try exp(x) out"
print(str:find("(%S*x%S*)")) -->  5    10    exp(x)
```

## To do it all in one assignment

use an inline function

```
newStr = (function(oldStr)
    from, till, found = (oldStr):find("(%S*x%S*)")
    return found
end)(str)
```

## For more information on lua patterns

[read about patterns in lua](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html), or try it yourself with this

```
s = "Deadline is 30/05/1999, firm"
date = "%d%d/%d%d/%d%d%d%d"
print(string.sub(s, string.find(s, date)))   --> 30/05/1999
print()

for patrnNr, patrn in pairs{
    "[%a[x]%a]?", 
    "[%a[x]%a*]?", 
    "([%a[x]%a*]?)", 
    "(%a*x%a*)",
    "(.+x.*)", 
    "(%S*x%S*)"} 
do
    for strNr, str in pairs{
        "Try exp(x) out", 
        "Try exp(y) out", 
        "Try sin(x) out", 
        "Try sin(y) out", 
        "Try exp    out", 
        "Try x y z  out", 
        "Try xy wx out"} 
    do
        print(patrn, str, str:gsub(patrn, '<%0>'), str:find(patrn))
    end
end

print()
print(("Try exp(x) out"):gsub("[%a[x]%a*]?", '<%0>')) --> <Try> <exp>(<x>) <out>    4
print(("Try exp(x) out"):find("(%S*x%S*)"))           --> 5    10    exp(x)
```